# Regex for only alphanumeric(only numeric should not be allowed)

Tags: regex, alphanumeric

I have tried

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$`

&

```
^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

but both are allowing numbers only as well.

Comment: Why don't you handle it in the code logic? (find a regex for alphanumeric, find a regex for numeric, combine the result)

Comment: I don't see a problem with your own regex https://regex101.com/r/M7R3ze/1

Comment: Where are you using this regex? What is the language / environment?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Explanation:

1. `^` start of string.
2. `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])`  positive look ahead, that ensures there exists
   one or more a-zA-Z; if true then :
3. `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` this matches one or more combination of alphanumeric characters.
4. `$` end of string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DNWl62/1/)

Comment: If both OP's regexes don't give them their expected output, yours wouldn't either.